# Attach an SSL/TLS certificate on WebClient calls using Netty

Tags: java, ssl, spring-webflux, spring-webclient, reactor-netty

I am using WebClient to make calls to external API which requires an SSL/TLS certificate. I am getting this certificate from AWS Certificate Manager with this API Result Object:

```
com.amazonaws.services.certificatemanager.model.GetCertificateResult
```

From this object I can only get the String content of the certificate, that is, the :

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MII.....MEKIEEI
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Now, I would like to create an SSL Context for Netty which I will then pass to my WebClient.

```
 SslContext sslContext = SslContextBuilder
                .forServer() // No parameters that seem to accept only the certificate body as String.
                .build();
```

but there are no methods on the `SslContextBuilder` that seem to accept on the certificate as String.

How can I successfully create an `SslContext`  with the certificate body as String and pass it to my `WebClient` so that I can make SSL/TLS enabled calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### To create X509Certificate from PEM string you need:

1. First you need to remove certificate headers from that PEM string.

   Headers are : `----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE------`
2. Decode the rest of the part using `Base64` to byte array. It is safer to use `Base64.getMimeDecoder()` than `Base64.getDecoder()`, otherwise you may run into issue `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character a`
3. Use `CertificateFactory` to convert byte stream to `X509Certificate`

So, the code would look like this:

```java
public static X509Certificate buildX509Certificate(String certPem) throws CertificateException {
    X509Certificate x509Certificate = null;

    if (Objects.nonNull(certPem)) {
        CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

        certPem = certPem.replace("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n", "")
                .replace("-----END CERTIFICATE-----", "");

        byte[] certBytes = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(certPem); // get cert bytes
        ByteArrayInputStream certInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(certBytes);
        x509Certificate = (X509Certificate)
                certificateFactory.generateCertificate(certInputStream); // generate certificate
    }
    return x509Certificate;
}
```

---

### To create SSLContext you need:

1. Create `KeyStore`
2. Put your certificate into it
3. Create `KeyManagerFactory` and init it from your keystore
4. Build `SSLContext` using `SslContextBuilder.forClient()`

So, the code would look like this:

```java
public static SslContext buildSSLContext(X509Certificate certificate, String alias) throws CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        KeyStoreException, IOException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    keyStore.load(null, null); // Use a null input stream + password to create an empty key store.

    keyStore.setCertificateEntry(alias, certificate); // add certificate to keystore

    KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, null);

    // Create an SSL context that uses that certificate
    return SslContextBuilder.forClient()
            .keyManager(keyManagerFactory)
            .build();
}
```

**Note**: `SSLContext` is from package `io.netty.handler.ssl`, not from `javax.net.ssl`

---

### To configure your WebClient with SSLContext you need:

1. Create `ReactorClientHttpConnector` with `HttpClient.create().secure()` where you can pass your `SSLContext`
2. Build WebClient passing your `ReactorClientHttpConnector` to `.clientConnector()` method

So, the code would look like this:

```java
X509Certificate x509Certificate = buildX509Certificate(certPem);
SslContext sslContext = buildSSLContext(x509Certificate, "my_cert");

ReactorClientHttpConnector reactorClientHttpConnector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.create()
        .secure(sslContextSpec -> sslContextSpec.sslContext(sslContext))
);
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
        .clientConnector(reactorClientHttpConnector)
        .build();
```

---

### UPDATED:

Probably in your case as your application is a client, you want just to verify identity of server. Then you should build `SSLContext` with `TrustManager`. Then your method `buildSSLContext()` would look like this:

```
public static SslContext buildSSLContext(X509Certificate certificate) throws IOException {
    // Create an SSL context that trusts that certificate
    return SslContextBuilder.forClient()
            .trustManager(certificate)
            .build();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, I am guided very well here! Let me implement this. One more question, the certificate's private key, is it required when creating the ssl context? Or just the certificate itself in enough? That part is not clear to me.

Comment: pem certificate does not contain a private key

Comment: FYI you don't need to de-PEM (remove label lines and de-base64); Java `CertificateFactory` can handle PEM by itself. (`KeyFactory` cannot, but would only be needed for a privatekey, which OP here doesn't appear to have.)